# spring-boot: response compression while executed from Maven command line

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm interested in enabling HTTP response compression for my Java 8 / spring-boot 1.3.2 / Maven 3.3 based application.

Following the spring-boot reference documentation from http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-enable-http-response-compression, I have added the following change to my application.properties:

server.compression.enabled=true

While the application started successfully before the above addition, with it the application fails to start with the following error when using the Maven command below:

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run
...
...
2016-01-26 09:48:48.802 ERROR 15204 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Compression is enabled, but GzipHandler is not on the classpath
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.miletwentyfour.client.Application.main(Application.java:43) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Compression is enabled, but GzipHandler is not on the classpath
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.createGzipHandler(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:192) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addHandlerWrappers(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:168) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:148) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

My next step, per the reference documentation section 64.18.2, was to add the following dependency to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
</dependency>
```

Using mvn:dependency:tree I can verify that jetty-servlets is included in the application as a compile time scoped dependency. Yet, the application fails to start with the same error output as above.

Can anyone please point out what I am missing and/or what do I need to do to get response compression to work successfully when launching the application from a Maven command line?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot 1.2 with properties that are new in 1.3. Upgrading to Spring Boot 1.3.x should fix your problem

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly fat fingered the version of spring-boot I'm using: I'm actually using 1.3.2, rather than 1.2.3. I have updated the original post to correct the typo.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing versions of Jetty's modules. Spring Boot 1.3 uses 9.2.x and, with that version, `spring-boot-starter-jetty` should give you all of the dependencies that you need.

Comment: I have verified that you are correct. While it's strange to me that Eclipse (and mvn dependency:tree) tell me that when I add the latest 9.2 version of jetty-servlets (9.2.14.v20151106) it says that I am manually overriding the version already in use. Yet, if I do not explicitly declare it within the pom.xml the needed class is never found and the app fails to start up.

Answer (score 0):

You need following maven dependancy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Good catch: I was adding jetty-servlet**s**, while you point out to try to add jetty-servlet. Yet, when I copy and paste your dependency into my pom.xml I receive the following error upon application startup:  org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.updateBean(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)V
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.REL

Answer (score 0):

Andy Wilkinson was correct and provided the needed information I was missing.

For the benefit of others, I was mixing Spring Boot 1.3 with the 9.**3**.x flavors of spring-jetty. Once I used the latest of spring-jetty 9.**2**.x -- I used 9.2.14.v20151106 -- my application started as normal.

To summarize, here the changes I made:

application.properties:

```
server.compression.enabled=true
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.14.v20151106</version>
</dependency>
```