# Decompress input request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I am using jetty as my embedded server in springboot application , I am receiving a request of body compressed json ( gzip ) with headers content-encoding:gzip . so how to add GZipHandler filter to decompress input request .

And If it is not possible to decompress input request using jetty then is there any other way to do it. please let me know

Comment: verify your spring version
can be related to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018231/spring-boot-response-compression-while-executed-from-maven-command-line

Comment: GZipHandler is a Jetty Handler (added to the Server handler tree), not a Servlet Filter (that would be added to the webapp filter chain).

Comment: You don’t normally need to do this. What problem are you having?

Comment: I want to decompress an input request which contains compressed json before hitting the rest controller . I get to know jetty has this feature of input request decompression , could you please let me know how to enable it

Comment: @Prakash5K4 please edit your question and provide some example of how you are using spring-boot, then someone here can help.  Right now there's nothing to work against. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask